# Presto Query Engine - Running mongoDB query to extract JSON type data

Tags: hive, mongodb-query, presto, trino

I am trying to query a record in Mongo with below schema in trino.

```js
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "123456789010111213"
    },
    "table": "personaldatacollection",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "eventString",
            "type": "row(..)",
            "hidden": false
        },           
        {
            "name": "personaldetailsmap",
            "type": "JSON",
            "hidden": false
        }
    ]
}
```

"personaldetailsmap" is in JSON format and also it is an Array which can have Array of Arrays in side it. And there are more than 200 or more attributes inside "personaldetailsmap" which has to be to be represented as columns as shown in the below query. Is there any proper way to extract these fields without repetetively using json_extract_scalar(..) many times?

```
select _id as id,eventString,domaindetails,technicaldetails,processStages,personaldetailsmap,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.firtName.0') as firtName,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.middleName.0') as middleName,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.lastName.0') as lastName,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.initials.0') as initials,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.age.0') as age,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.birthMonth.0') as birthMonth,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.birthDate.0') as birthDate,
json_extract_scalar(personaldetailsmap, '$.0.birthYear.0') as birthYear,
.
.
.
.
.
from "test".db01.personaldatacollection;
```

Comment: So what is the actual query engine here - mongo or presto? Also please share some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to flatten the array fields using Trino. Instead of fetching these values one at a time you can simply flatten them using `CROSS JOIN UNNEST. Below is an example to flatten the JSON data you have shared .

```
select field.name,field.hidden from <table-name> CROSS JOIN UNNEST(fields) as t(field)
```